# Is there a way to give ownership of new tables to the schema owner automatically?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When a user creates a new table in Snowflake using a user role, is it possible to automatically transfer the ownership of the new table to the owner role of the schema rather than to the user role that creates it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the OWNERSHIP privileges to all FUTURE tables that will be created to a specific user.

Command for this would be as follows:

```
grant ownership on future tables in schema <name of the schema> to role <owner role of the schema>;
```